# list comprehension without if but with else

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My question aims to use the else condition of a for-loop in a list comprehension.

example:

```
empty_list = []
def example_func(text):
    for a in text.split():
        for b in a.split(","):
            empty_list.append(b)
        else:
            empty_list.append(" ")
```

I would like to make it cleaner by using a list comprehension with both for-loops.

But how can I do this by including an escape-clause for one of the loops (in this case the 2nd).
I know I can use if with and without else in a list comprehension. But how about using else without an if statement.

Is there a way, so the interpreter will understand it as escape-clause of a for loop?

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers! In fact im trying to translate morse code.

The input is a string, containing morse codes.
Each word is separated by 3 spaces. Each letter of each word is separated by 1 space.

```
def decoder(code): 
    str_list = [] 
    for i in code.split("   "): 
        for e in i.split(): 
            str_list.append(morse_code_dic[e]) 
        else: 
            str_list.append(" ") 
     return "".join(str_list[:-1]).capitalize()

print(decoder(".. -   .-- .- ...   .-   --. --- --- -..   -.. .- -.--"))
```

I want to break down the whole sentence into words, then translate each word.
After the inner loop (translation of one word) is finished, it will launch its escape-clause else, adding a space, so that the structure of the whole sentence will be preserved. That way, the 3 Spaces will be translated to one space.

Comment: Your inner `for` will always complete, so the `else` looks like it will always run regardless. It seems like that should just be a separate entry in `a.split(",")`. `empty_list = list(itertools.chain(a.split(","), [" "]))`? Or just `empty_list = a.split(","); empty_list.append(" ")`. I think you're complicating it. The original `for` loop isn't needed, so a list comprehension will be contrived.

Comment: List comprehensions cannot use `break`, therefore, the optional [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) clause of "regular" loops does not make sense within a list comprehension.

Comment: Is the point of your else  to always add a space when your outer for loop completes?

Comment: I suppose you could do something like `[x for a in text.split() for x in list(a.split(",")) + [' ']]` (untested) but to be honest, I'm not sure that it's an improvement to write it as a list comp. You do however want to remove that redundant `else:` line for reasons stated by Carcigenicate.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I updated the initial question so you can see what's my intention.

Comment: The `basic` tag is for the BASIC programming language, not to indicate the level of the question.

Comment: @0x5453. I've shown how to insert limited break functionality into a comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, that `else` does not really make all that much sense, since the purpose of an `else` after a `for` loop is actually to hold code for conditional execution if the loop terminates normally (i.e. not via `break`), which your loop *always* does, thus it is always executed.

So this is not really an answer to the question how to do *that* in a list comprehension, but more of an alternative. Instead of adding spaces after all words, then removing the last space and joining everything together, you could just use two nested `join` generator expressions, one for the sentence and one for the words:

```
def decoder(code): 
    return " ".join("".join(morse_code_dic[e] for e in i.split())
                    for i in code.split("   ")).capitalize()
```

Comment: Thanks, did not think about that solution!
In fact, I was just curious if the idea of an escape-clause in a list-comprehension would be possible. But looking at your solution, I don't think anymore, that an escape-clause is necessarily needed.

Comment: @Jero. This is definitely the right way to do it, but I've added an answer that shows how to actually implement limited break and else functionality in a comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `else` clause in your particular example is pointless because it always runs. Let's contrive an example that would let us investigate the possibility of simulating a `break` and `else`.

Take the following string:

```
s = 'a,b,c b,c,d c,d,e, d,e,f'
```

Let's say you wanted to split the string by spaces and commas as before, but you only wanted to preserve the elements of the inner split up to the first occurrence of `c`:

```
out = []
for i in s.split(): 
    for e in i.split(','):
        if e == 'c':
            break
        out.append(e)
    else: 
        out.append('-')
```

The `break` can be simulated using the arcane two-arg form of `iter`, which accepts a callable and a termination value:

```
>>> x = list('abcd')
>>> list(iter(iter(x).__next__, 'c'))
['a', 'b']
```

You can implement the `else` by [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the inner iterable with `['-']`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> x = list('abcd')
>>> list(iter(chain(x, ['-'])
.__next__, 'c'))
['a', 'b']
>>> y = list('def')
>>> list(iter(chain(y, ['-'])
.__next__, 'c'))
['d', 'e', 'f', '-']
```

Notice that the placement of `chain` is crucial here. If you were to chain the dash to the outer iterator, it would always be appended, not only when `c` is not encountered:

```
>>> list(chain(iter(iter(x).__next__, 'c'), ['-']))
['a', 'b', '-']
```

You can now simulate the entire nested loop with a single expression:

```
from itertools import chain

out = [e for i in s.split() for e in iter(chain(i.split(','), ['-']).__next__, 'c')]
```

Comment: This is a great academic example if you want to learn some of Python's more esoteric features.  But please never, ever do this in "real" code!

Comment: Neat. Using `takewhile` might even be a bit cleaner, and more versatile, e.g. as `list(takewhile("c".__ne__, chain(x, ["-"])))`

Comment: @tobias_k. That's a good idea. What I'm trying to figure out is how to simulate the behaviour in the nested loop when `out.append(e)` comes before `if ...: break`.